# View-transition API does not work in Microsoft Edge 122 or Opera on macOS while working perfectly in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-edge, view-transitions-api

The view-transition API works in Google Chrome but not in Microsoft Edge 122. Both browsers should be supported according to the compatibility table. I am using macOS. There is no JavaScript involved. It works in Chrome just by using these two HTML files.

The `index.html` page navigates to `child.html` page when image is clicked. The `child.html` page has the same image but bigger, and the view transition API works nicely in Chrome as it handles the size difference.

Here are my HTML files:

index.html

```html
<meta name="view-transition" content="same-origin">

<a href="child.html">
    <img class="img-small" src="https://images.rawpixel.com/image_800/cHJpdmF0ZS9sci9pbWFnZXMvd2Vic2l0ZS8yMDIyLTA1L3NrOTc5MS1pbWFnZS1rd3Z1amE5Ni5qcGc.jpg">
</a>

<style>
    .img-small {
        view-transition-name: small;
        width: 600px;
    }
</style>
```

child.html

```html
<meta name="view-transition" content="same-origin">

<a href="index.html">
    <img class="img-small" src="https://images.rawpixel.com/image_800/cHJpdmF0ZS9sci9pbWFnZXMvd2Vic2l0ZS8yMDIyLTA1L3NrOTc5MS1pbWFnZS1rd3Z1amE5Ni5qcGc.jpg">
</a>

<body></body>

<style>
    .img-small {
        view-transition-name: small;
        width: 900px;
    }
</style>
```

Do you know where might be the problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Could you also share your JavaScript code for the View-transition API? A minimal example should be enough.

Comment: @KendrickLi There is no JavaScript code. The view transition API works in Chrome just using these 2 HTML files. You can try it in latest Chrome. It works as is. But not in Edge or Opera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have enabled the Chrome flag: **chrome://flags/#view-transition-on-navigation**. That's why it works in Chrome instead of Microsoft Edge without any JavaScript code.

Unfortunately, Microsoft Edge currently does not have this flag, so view-transition does not work. You may expect this flag to be added in the future. You can also send feedback (Alt+Shift+I) in Microsoft Edge to request this flag.

Comment: Thanks! Yes I have it enabled. So this means that I cannot use CSS-only view transition in other browsers than Chrome?

Comment: @user7289922 Correct.